# Creating TS file from MP4 file - Differing durations

Tags: ffmpeg

I am running the following command to crop an MP4 file

```
-i "C:\FFMPEG\Temp\S3\2ad239d1-f4b9-4854-afe4-7e28157893daHighRes.mp4" -q:v 0 -y -ss 00:00:01.000 -to 00:00:29.834 -vf "fade=t=out:st=29.334:d=0.500, scale=iw*min(1080/iw\,720/ih):ih*min(1080/iw\,720/ih),pad=1080:720:(1080-iw)/2:(720-ih)/2" "C:\FFMPEG\Temp\Crops\5ae9806e32ab040978d97013_0.ts"
```

As you can see I want to crop a video of exactly 28834 milliseconds long.  However the created file when inspecting it via ffprobe is 28873 milliseconds long.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your frames-per-second is not 1000.

Videos don't encode milliseconds, they encode frames. They can only encode a whole number of frames. If the duration you asked for doesn't divide evenly with the duration of the frames, then the output duration is going to be slightly longer.

For a duration of 28834 ms, possible frame-rates are `1000`, `500`, `1000/13 ≈ 76.9`, `500/13 ≈ 38.5`, `1000/1109`, `500/1109`, `1000/14417` and `500/14417`.